# StackOverflow exception on Tab Host

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-style-tabhost

I am using this code to open new activity

```
View view = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity("main_jobs", 
                    new Intent(context,Job_Description.class)
                    .putExtra("line", str_line).putExtra("limit",str_limit)
                    .putExtra("limit",""+0)
                    .putExtra("Alert", false)
                    .putExtra("str_location", str_loc)
                    .putExtra("str_Descrption",str_descjob)
                    .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP))
                    .getDecorView();
                                          setContentView(view);
```

But when I open many child Activity then Run time Stack Ower Flow Exception Occur

```
01-08 14:53:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(4577): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-08 14:53:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(4577): java.lang.StackOverflowError
01-08 14:53:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at    android.view.View.getDrawableState(View.java:14034)
01-08 14:53:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at android.widget.TextView.onDraw(TextView.java:4825)
01-08 14:53:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13458)
01-08 14:53:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13342)
01-08 14:53:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2929)
01-08 14:53:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2799)
01-08 14:53:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13461)
01-08 14:53:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13342)
01-08 14:53:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2929)
01-08 14:53:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2799)
01-08 14:53:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13461)
01-08 14:53:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13342)
01-08 14:53:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2929)
01-08 14:53:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2799)
01-08 14:53:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13340)
01-08 14:53:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2929)
01-08 14:53:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2799)
01-08 14:53:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13340)
01-08 14:53:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2929)
01-08 14:53:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2799)
01-08 14:53:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13340)
01-08 14:53:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2929)
01-08 14:53:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2799)
01-08 14:53:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13340)
01-08 14:53:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2929)
01-08 14:53:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2799)
01-08 14:53:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13340)
01-08 14:53:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2929)
01-08 14:53:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2799)
01-08 14:53:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at  android.view.View.draw(View.java:13340)
01-08 14:53:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2929)
01-08 14:53:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2799)
01-08 14:53:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13340)
01-08 14:53:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2929)
01-08 14:53:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2799)
01-08 14:53:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13340)
01-08 14:53:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2929)
01-08 14:53:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2799)
01-08 14:53:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13340)
01-08 14:53:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2929)
01-08 14:53:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2799)
01-08 14:53:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13340)
 01-08 14:53:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2929)
 01-08 14:53:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2799)
 01-08 14:53:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13340)
 01-08 14:53:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2929)
01-08 14:53:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2799)
01-08 14:53:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13340)
01-08 14:53:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2929)
01-08 14:53:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2799)
01-08 14:53:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13340)
01-08 14:53:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2929)
01-08 14:53:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2799)
01-08 14:53:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13340)
01-08 14:53:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2929)
 01-08 14:53:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2799)
 01-08 14:53:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13340)
 01-08 14:53:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2929)
 01-08 14:53:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2799)
 01-08 14:53:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13340)
 01-08 14:53:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2929)
01-08 14:53:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2799)
01-08 14:53:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13340)
01-08 14:53:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2929)
01-08 14:53:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2799)
01-08 14:53:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13340)
01-08 14:53:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2929)
01-08 14:53:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2799)
01-08 14:53:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13340)
01-08 14:53:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2929)
01-08 14:53:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2799)
01-08 14:53:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13340)
01-08 14:53:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2929)
01-08 14:53:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2799)
01-08 14:53:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at android.view
```

I am New IN Android. Then I don't have any idea about this error.

Please Help Me How I can Fix This Error

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: How many tabs you have ?

Comment: It seems you have a `<selector>` drawable xml whose state drawables are wrong, or are referenced cyclically. And I guess that drawable is background of tab's view.

Comment: I have only four Tabs but i have many Activity.

Comment: Please Help Me How i can fix this issue